# Word Javascript API: Is there a way to access the Word Objects for which there is no Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I contemplated using the Javascript API for Word. However some objects do not seem to be accessible/available in the API such as AutoShapes for example.

I am not a JS pro. However, I wonder whether there would be a work-around that allows accessing all the objects, props, methods, etc available in the VBA Object model.

Comment: Have you had a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview ?

Comment: Of course. This is where I realized that the api does not cover all the objects specially the Shapes collection and not all the ContentControls collection.